# Canceling accuracy setting on android- nubia Z17

Tags: location-services, zte

when I first used the GPS while driving i accidently checked 'Remember this setting' and consented into the program (high accuracy). I would like to undo this, but i dont know how. 
Can someone please help me? i dont want to erase all the data from the device of course...
Nir

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Android version, this may change a little bit:

1. Open your app drawer
2. Click Settings
3. Click on Location
4. Click on Mode

Comment: hi, once we turn on the GPS the mode is automatically is on high accuracy. still, the GPS is not working, any other solutions?